# Way to recover my corrupted php file in my thumb drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

My files are there but when I open the file it gives my weird looking letters.

[image]
[image]

My res folder is now a file for some reason. So I'm pretty sure it got corrupted I just don't know how to fix it. I've googled how to recover it but the ones I tried does not work. So if you guys got any ideas please let me know. I've really worked on on this project and I don't want to start over again! Thank you!

Comment: Can't tell what filesystem that is; some are definitely more sensitive to unsafe eject and harder to fix than others. If you could identify the filesystem that would help, and to part with an idea (not low-work): Since the PHP file would be mostly text, you could take an image of the disk and run it through a utility like strings. You might get your old data, new data or both, depending on what you/it was doing when it couldn't finish (wear-leveling, updating the allocation tables, etc).

Comment: @ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ How would I check what filesystem it is?

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper, what Operating System is this on ?  NTFS / HFS+ / Ext4 /Btrfs /XFS are common Filesystems for the common three OSes

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper: Right-click drive in Explorer, look for *File system*. Not that knowing if it's NTFS, exFAT or FAT32 would make any difference at all. Try some data recovery utilities but if they don't work then you've just learnt the importance of keeping backups of important work.